# Multiple Permalink for Single Post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I have a worpdress website that is set with a permalink structure to:

```
mywebsite.com/%author%/%postname%/
```

Now, I have a post that is written by multiple authors - what we wanted to achieve is that we should suppose to be able to access the post by going to any of the author in the url such as:

```
mywebsite.com/author1/mypost
mywebsite.com/author2/mypost
```

This actually works, however for some reason when I go to:

```
mywebsite.com/author2/mypost
```

this redirects to this:

```
mywebsite.com/author1/mypost
```

I think this is due to the base permalink wordpress enforces?

How do I make it so that when I go to the link of a certain author, it will retain the author in the permalink?

eg.
Going to `mywebsite.com/author2/mypost` should direct to `mywebsite.com/author2/mypost`

Comment: What you want to achieve is not good for SEO purposes, since multiple links should never link to the same content.

Comment: Yes, fully understood and knew about the implications and it's okay.

Comment: https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/WPSE-Plugins/blob/master/custom-author-base.php ====> Checkout this link. i think it will solve your problem